How can i import my KMM Library to any kotlin application?
I have a KMM Library project and i want to test it on an app. I published library as mavenLocal and it is in my .m2 folder. When i trying to implement and import my library from my app gradle could not find my library. By the way i added mavenLocal to repositories in my app but still there is no library.
Here is my app's gradle files:
build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation("com.kartaca.sumersdk:sumersdk:1.0.0")
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.kartaca.sumer"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


settings.gradle.kts:
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "My_Application"
include(":androidApp")
include(":shared")

